# I keep getting a 503 error when trying to import a database using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

As I say I'm trying to import a database to a live server, it uploads but then I get a 503 error.

I can't seem to be able to create a database either, it says loading then nothing actually happens.

I'm running apache2 and everything seemed to work fine a few weeks ago.

I'm able to ssh into my server and create a database using the same username as I use to log into phpmyadmin.

It seems it's only phpmyadmin that's having this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is the file you are trying to import? The php.ini defaults to 2mb by default, and if the db file you are trying to import is larger than that, you might encounter the error you are referencing.

Try editing your php.ini following items to meet your requirements.

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 40M
```

Comment: It's 12mb, but I swear I changed it, I'll have a look.

Comment: ah... it was max file size 12mb haha doh.

Comment: Thought that was it but it's still doing it :/

Comment: I modified all those fields and still the problem :(